Optimize a convex difference of quad forms
I have an optimisation problem of the form:
$$\min_x c^T x + \| V x\|^2_2 + \| D x\|^2_2  - \| W x\|^2_2$$
Subject to linear constraints.
$D$ is diagonal and $V$, $W$ are non-square matrices. I know that:
$$Q = V V^T - WW^T + D^2 \succ 0$$
Ensuring convexity of the problem.
Can we rewrite this problem so that it is accepted by a DCP solver like CVXPY, while keeping inherent low-rank nature of the problem ?

Surely the solution is $x=-{1 \over 2} Q^{-1} c$?

That would be true without the linear equality constraints. In the original post, though, don’t we need $V^\top V - W^\top W + D^2 \succ 0$ instead of the stated condition to ensure (strict) convexity?

Yup exactly ! Q is (strictly) positive definite

I would consider the dual problem. Suppose your linear equality constraints are given by $Ax = b$. We form the Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L}(x, v) = c^\top x + \lVert V x \rVert_2^2 + \lVert D x \rVert_2^2 - \lVert W x \rVert_2^2 + v^\top ( Ax - b )$$
The Lagrange dual function is defined to be
$$g(v) = \min_x \mathcal{L}(x, v)$$
We can solve this minimization problem to find
$$g(v) = \mathcal{L}\left( -\frac{1}{2} Q^{-1}( c + A^{\top}v), v \right)$$
which gives rise to the dual problem $\max_v g(v)$. Lastly, by strong duality the optimal objective value of the dual problem is equal to the optimal objective value of the primal problem.

The point is that in my practical case forming $Q$ and inverting is pretty much intractable. Keeping the low rank decomposition would be way nicer.
